# Best intro to iOS for Python/PHP/C# Coder

Tags: python, .net, ios

I really would like to start getting into Objective C coding, specifically so I can write applications for iOS.

My coding background is that I have written C# .NET GUI Windows apps and PHP web scripts for years; I've also become a very good Python coder in the past year. I have written hundreds of useful command-line Python scripts, and also a few GUI apps using wxPython successfully. I also wrote VB6 GUI apps way back in the day, and of course, I cut my teeth on QuickBASIC in DOS. ;-)

I understand OOP concepts: I understand classes, methods, properties and the like. I use OOP a lot in Python, and obviously use it extensively in C#.

I haven't actually taken the time to really get good at C or C++, however I am able to write simple "test" programs to accomplish small tasks. The problem is that I understand the **syntax** just fine, but the APIs can be very different depending on platform, and accomplishing the same thing in C on Linux at the command line is totally different than accomplishing it in Windows in a GUI.

I've looked over a few books out there for iOS coding but they seem to assume little to no programming knowledge and quickly bore me, and I can't easily find the information I really need buried among all of the "here's what an object is" or "this is called a class and a method" stuff...

I also tried the Stanford lectures on iTunes U, but I found myself struggling with the MVC concepts and the idea of setting up different files for "implementation" and "header" and all of that...

Is there any resources that you guys can think of that would be good for me to get started with iOS?

It's also worth noting I have dabbled with PyObjC a little on Mac and therefore do understand a LITTLE about the NS foundation classes and such, and I've also looked at Apple's reference documentation and I'm sure that once I get the basics down I could put good use to it, but I still don't know how to actually get a functional iOS app that does something useful going.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already a *very good Python coder* and your main objective is to develop apps for iOS, then you don't need Objective-C necessarily.

Stick to Python and take a look at [Kivy](http://kivy.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I learned to write iOs apps from the CS 193P iPhone Application Development course on iTunes U. It's fantastic and I highly recommend it if you are sure iOs is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I know Python and C++ before I start to learn Objective-C, I remember at that point I:

1. bought a book from Amazon and follow the demos in the book: [Beginning-iOS-Development-Exploring-SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430245123).
2. watch every lesson of [Developing Apps for iOS by Paul Hegarty](https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774).
3. follow some basic ios tutorials from google and search stackoverflow when have questions.

But later on I started to forget things, so **I realized I need to have a app to do! I need to know what app I want to build! This is the key point of driving me keep learning**. So I decide to build a photo sharing app just similar to instagram, and I found two source really help me on this:

1. Open-source photo-sharing app Anypic from Parse:[link](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic). It is a show case from Parse to show their service, and you can find it in app store too.
2. [www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/). Now there have 285 high quality iOS programing tutorials and counting, most of tutorials start to treat you as beginner and teach you step by step, and also highly recommended to buy their book too.

Hope this helps:-)

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten more from Erica Sadun's books than any of the others, personally.  iOS apps use a lot of animation and graphics, by necessity, and her code examples are clean and concise.  They aren't beginner's books but you sound as though you're not a beginning coder.  They hit on a lot of topics it is hard to find much on.

If you're willing to work through the sample programs, I found iPad iOS 6 Development Essentials to be comprehensive (Neil Smith).  However, it tends to focus on the visual IDE of xCode which I think is lousy and chose not to use at all; if you plan to use it, then that would be a good resource imo.  Also, I got a book that covered Objective C only (Aaron Hillegass) which I thought was good.  The iOS book from the same author was not good for me, because it depended on you working prior chapter examples to proceed to later chapters, which for me was a waste of time, so I bailed out of it quickly.  I also got Pro Core Data (Privat and Warner) which I found to be of limited (actually, little) value for the same reason as the Hillegass iOS book -- the examples are too big and not to the point.

And, of course, Google.